# Recursion Error. Having trouble understanding the logic with recursive functions

Tags: python, function, recursion

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=1000)
def recursiveFunc(x):
    if x == 1:
        return 1
    elif x > 1 :
        return recursiveFunc(x) + recursiveFunc(x+1) #This is the part i'm having doubts about. 

for x in range(1, 101):
     print(x, ":", recursiveFunc(x))
```

This functions is supposed to generate consecutive numbers starting from 1 to 100 using recursion.

Comment: I'd highly recommend going through the intuition behind recursion first. Your function in its current form does not "get down to" the base case, so to speak. Also, as a rule of thumb, if you are ever using a recursion, avoid any loop in the code when you are starting, it is easier to keep looping and recursion separate when learning them.

Comment: Stick a print statement in the func to see what is going on: `print(f'called with {x}')`. Except for the first time, always `called with 2`, which means that the function is never returning so that `x` can be incremented.

Comment: In order to calculate recursiveFunc(100), it also needs recursiveFunc(101). For 101, it needs 102 and for 102 it needs... you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have to learn very well all the recursion story, it takes time... you have to visualize what the program is executing in every step. My advice is to draw the first times the stack buffer with every call of the function

---

The solution of your problem is:

```
def recursiveFunc(x):
    if x == 1:
        return 1
    elif x > 1 :
        return 1 + recursiveFunc(x-1) #This is the part I've changed.

for x in range(1, 101):
    print(x, ":", recursiveFunc(x))
```

Why your doesn't work? Cause when the function calls return, return start the new function recursiveFunc(x)... but it's just the same of before! so there is an infinite loop.
Furthermore if you add like recursiveFunc(x+1) and you pass x that are positive you will never made the comparison x == 0 cause x it's growing call after call.

Answer (score 0):

Here I'll try to clear things up for you :)

Writing a function that lists numbers from 1 to n is simple.
If we tried running this function

```
def recursiveFunc(i):
   print(i)
   recursiveFunc(i+1)

recursiveFunc(1)
```

It would print out 1, then 2, 3.... But would never stop.

```
1
2
3
...
```

To fix this we add a second parameter

```
def recursiveFunc(i, n):
   if i > n:
      return

   print(i)
   recursiveFunc(i+1)

recursiveFunc(1, 100)
```

This will escape the function when it passes n, in this case, 100

```
1
2
...
100
```

if you wanted to return the series rather than just print it out you could do something like this:

```
def recursiveFunc(i, n):
   if i >= n:
      return str(i)

   return str(i) + ", " + str(recursiveFunc(i + 1, n))

print(recursiveFunc(1, 100))
```

Then the output would be

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100
```